# Automatic logoff user from Terminal Service Manager

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2

I wanted to ask, is it possible to automatic logoff users from the terminal after specific idletime? Because currently I'm having an internship at a company and it kinda new for me to know anything about the servers and they haven't teach me about the server yet, I consider this as self learning. And also my supervisor asked me to logoff them after a specific idletime which I know very inefficient. If I not mistaken, the company is using Windows Server 2008 R2. If any relevant links or question that can help would be more appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: `is it possible to automatic logoff users from the terminal after specific idletime?` - Yes it is. - https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754272(v=ws.11).aspx

Comment: @joeqwerty I did actually refer to that link given by you, but somehow I could not find Remote Desktop Services in Administrative Tools. Which lead me to post a question here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I adapted the scheduled task described in: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9946331/bat-file-to-close-program-after-5-minutes-of-inactivity

From cmd on the server that you're trying to avoid having a stale session on, enter:

```
schtasks /create /u {yourusernamehere} /sc ONIDLE /i {idlelimit-int-inminutes} /tn  "Idlelogoffformgmtuser" /tr C:\Windows\System32\logoff.exe
```

Replace fields where appropriate; I don't have access to a 2k8R2 currently so I can't verify the location of logoff.exe but I think that should be right.

schtasks will prompt for your password after entering this as well.

This should create a scheduled task that'll check sessions with your user specifically that need to be logged off after idling a certain time. If you need to tinker, refer to the documentation of schtasks - it's a pretty powerful command imo.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc725744(v=ws.11).aspx

Hopefully this helps,

Comment: if you don't mind, can you give me an example for /i {idlelimit-int-inmunutes} ? Let's say i wanted to logoff users that idletime is more than 20minutes.

Comment: it's shorthand for the designated idle limit given you by your boss, in integer form, that counts minutes. So for your question, it'd go "/i 20".

Hope this helps,

Comment: thanks lot! Just one more question, "Idlelogoffmgmtuser" is a task name right? My question is that, task name can be any?

Comment: Sure; knock yourself out. My only suggestions are name it something you won't forget and won't freak your customers out